# Pause/Resume WPF storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I've read about a dozen articles on how to pause and resume an WPF storyboard, but I just can't get it to work.
Here's my problem: I have a User control with a storyboard. The storyboard looks like this:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="TheStoryboard" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
      <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="Arc1">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="90"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="180"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:6" Value="270"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:8" Value="360"/>
      </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
   </Storyboard>
  </UserControl.Resources>
```

Simple enough, it makes an ark spin forever.
Now in the code behind I have a dependency property which is bound to a Boolean value indicating when the animation should be spinning or stopped. This triggers a method which should, in theory, pause or resume the animation. 
It looks something like this:

```
private void SetStoryBoardActivity(bool play)
    {
      var storyboard = (Storyboard)this.Resources["TheStoryboard"];
      if (play)
      {
        storyboard.Resume();
      }
      else
      {
        storyboard.Pause();       
      }
    }
```

The execution path enters the method as intended, however the animation doesn't stop when calling Pause(); I've tried

```
    storyboard.Stop();
    storyboard.Stop(this);
    storyboard.Stop(this.Arc1);
    storyboard.Freeze();
    storyboard.Pause();
    storyboard.Pause(this);
    storyboard.Pause(this.Arc1);
```

but nothing seems to work. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: is SetStoryBoardActivity method being hit?

Comment: Yes, the method is hit as intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the Answer in my case seems to be visual states.
I manged to make this work in the  following manner:
I moved the storyboard to a visual state manager like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">  
 <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
  <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Animation">
    <VisualState x:Name="On">
     <Storyboard  RepeatBehavior="Forever">
       <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="Arc1">
       <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
       <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="90"/>
       <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="180"/>
       <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:6" Value="270"/>
       <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:8" Value="360"/>
      </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>          
     </Storyboard>
    </VisualState>
   <VisualState x:Name="Off"/>
  </VisualStateGroup>
 </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>    
 <ed:Arc x:Name="Arc1" ArcThickness="15" ArcThicknessUnit="Pixel" StartAngle="30" EndAngle="150" Fill="#C0375E77" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="200" Width="200" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stretch="None" Stroke="#FF204050" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
  <ed:Arc.RenderTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
      <ScaleTransform/>
      <SkewTransform/>
      <RotateTransform/>
      <TranslateTransform/>
    </TransformGroup>
   </ed:Arc.RenderTransform>
  </ed:Arc>
 </Grid>
```

Please note that the visual state manager is not placed in the control's resources, but in the control's main container.
Where ed is:

```
xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing"
```

And the SetStoryBoardActivity method becomes:

```
 private void SetStoryBoardActivity()
 {
   VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, this.AnimationActive ? "On" : "Off", true);
 }
```

Where this.AnimationActive is the dependency property mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 1):

How about trying out with:

```
Storyboard storyboard = (Storyboard)this.Resources["TheStoryboard"];

private void BeginStoryBoard()
{
  storyboard.begin(this, true);
}

private void SetStoryBoardActivity(bool play)
{
  if (play)
  {
    storyboard.Resume(this);
  }
  else
  {
    storyboard.Pause(this);       
  }
}
```